# to combine html and flash

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sUrl = "C:/Documents and Settings/stajer_it/Desktop/Yeni Klasör/inna.flv";
            string sBaslangic = "10.000";
            string sBitis = "15.000";


            lblObje.Text = @"<object classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' width='550' height='400' id='player' align='middle'>
<param name='movie' value='player.swf?url="+sUrl+"&bas="+sBaslangic+"&bit="+sBitis+ @"' />
<param name='quality' value='high' />
<param name='bgcolor' value='#ffffff' />
<param name='play' value='true' />
<param name='loop' value='true' />
<param name='wmode' value='window' />
<param name='scale' value='showall' />
<param name='menu' value='true' />
<param name='devicefont' value='false' />
<param name='salign' value='' />
<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='player.swf' width='550' height='400'>
 <param name='movie' value='player.swf' />
 <param name='quality' value='high' />
 <param name='bgcolor' value='#ffffff' />
 <param name='play' value='true' />
 <param name='loop' value='true' />
 <param name='wmode' value='window' />
 <param name='scale' value='showall' />
 <param name='menu' value='true' />
 <param name='devicefont' value='false' />
 <param name='salign' value='' />
 <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />
 <!--<param name='url' value='http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/barsandtone.flv' />
 <param name='bas' value='3' />
 <param name='son' value='5' />-->


<!--<![endif]-->
 <a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash'>
  <img src='http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Adobe Flash Player’ı Edinin' />
 </a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>";

        }
```

i want to run this code to show flv video from as3.but when i run this code,it doesn't work.thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have more then a couple of things wrong with this code.

1. understanding of the sandbox
2. the code you wrote to show the flash object.

I would recommend 2 things
1. the path to the FLV should be a relative path
2. embed the SWF onto the HTML using SWFObject, it'll be so much easier, browser cross platform and more.

It could be that some security definitions in your browser do not allow the Flash virtual machine to run a local (off the disk) file

Check out this:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/